# How can I be sure I will receive all of my pension payments when I have worked for many employers?

Tags: united-kingdom, retirement, pension

Most people will work for many employers in their lifetime. In the UK, your employer contributes to your pension.

My question is, when I come to retire how can I be guaranteed to have access to all of the many pensions I may have contributed to over the years?

Comment: By keeping all the payslips you receive which show your employers' contributions towards retirement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I've had several jobs over the last decade, I've typically run two pension plans - a private one which I use for consolidating all my previous pensions into and my current corporate one (often doesn't allow consolidating) where I take advantage of the corporate benefits associated with it (large corporate institutions typically match your own contributions or contribute a fixed percentage of salary as a perk).

This allows me to not worry about the previous pension schemes I was a part of as they are in a single place. With the very last corporate job I had, I was not allowed to keep my pension pot under their scheme terms (unlike with a few others where it was allowed to stay in the scheme but contributions were no longer allowed by either party) and so when I left, I provided the details of my private pension plan and the pot was transferred into it by my employer.

I've since turned to contracting and consolidated all my previous pensions into a single private pension pot which I still contribute to every month.